# Syncing data from cloudant db to pouchdb

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb, cloudant

I am making Ionic 2 mobile App in which I want to sync my data from cloudant db to pouchdb.

My cloudant db has thousands and thousands of data and I don't want all of it to sync with pouchdb since it will take a lot of time. I just want last 10 records to sync with pouchdb and those recent 10 records should be displayed on mobile app.
Is it possible?

Iam not able to find any good solution in pouchdb. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PouchDB includes the ability to perform [filtered replication](https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html). You could potentially use filtered replication to replicate only the 10 most recent records (though you'll need to clearly define what "recent" means, which presents its own challenges). However, assuming you're doing a unidirectional replication (i.e. from Cloudant to PouchDB) then once a document has been replicated to your PouchDB database it will remain in your PouchDB database until it is deleted. So, if you do a filtered replication that brings in the 10 most recent documents, and then do another filtered replication then brings in another set of 10 most recent document, you will now have 20 documents in your PouchDB database (assuming there are at least 10 "new" documents generated between the first and second replication). If you took this approach then you'd need to create a mechanism for deleting "older" documents.

Do you need this feature to work offline? If not, then you could simply [use PouchDB as a client library by pointing it directly to the Cloudant database](https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html#remote-databases), and then use the [changes feed](https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html) feature to retrieve the 10 most recently modified documents from the Cloudant database.